# Playing video alongside CCGameView

Tags: android, video, cocossharp

I have a FrameLayout with a TextView, ImageView, CCGameView and a VideoView. In the game view I have a simple sprite and label. I have one video playing in the VideoView and one Image in the ImageView.

When the application first starts the image and video are displayed properly but as soon as the gameview loads the video can no longer be seen.

I even tried doing a `bringToFront()` on the VideoView after the GameView has loaded, in case it was a z order issue, but nothing.

Can anyone help or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question just in case it helps someone else. I put the video view before the CCGameView in the FrameLayout. However the ImageView and TextView I have in the layout are added after the CCGameView. With this order the Gameview is in the background.